# Any advantage in TAR's built-in archive support?

Tags: tar

Given the option to call:

```
tar -cI "xz -9" -f my_archive.tar.xz my_path/
```

and

```
XZ_OPT=-9 tar cJf my_archive.tar.xz my_path/
```

The result of both is exactly the same size.

Is there a good reason to use the built-in `J` to support `xz` over passing in the `xz` command?

Comment: do they result in the same compression?

Comment: Updated question.

Answer (score 2):

You have to type and remember less with the `-J` option, at least with default compression settings. Note that this option calls the `xz` executable in your PATH, just like `-I`.

And with `-I` you have full control over the compressor, its path and the options you want to use which might not be controllable via environment variables.

In your example it's a matter of taste.

Another option would be to `tar` the target files and pipe the output to the compressor:

```
tar cf - my_path | xz -9 > my_archive.tar.xz
```